# MS Exchange Server NTLM Authentication Issue 501 5.1.7 Invalid address

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I have a web application that needs to send email notifications to users for specific tasks.

I have a screen where the administrator of the site configures the mail server settings, which would then be used by the application to send out emails whenever needed.

Below is a highly abridged version of the code that we have:

```
public static boolean sendEmail(String toAddress, String fromAddress, String userName, String userPassword,String smtpHost, String portNumber, String emailSubject,String emailBody) {
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.

       String to = toAddress;

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = fromAddress;//change accordingly
      final String username = userName;//change accordingly
      final String password = userPassword;//change accordingly

      // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
      String host = smtpHost;

      Properties props = new Properties();

      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", portNumber);
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", portNumber);

      //For NTLM
      props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.domain","");

      // Get the Session object.
      SMTPAuthenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator(username, password);
      props.put("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);


      try {
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
         InternetAddress.parse(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject(emailSubject);

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText(emailBody);

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

      } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    return true;
   }
```

It worked fine, until we deployed our application in one of our client environments. Our client uses an on-premise MS Exchange Server that uses **NTLM authentication**

Here, we need to specify the from and to addresses as `MYDOMAIN\s.sriram` as opposed to `s.sriram@mydomain.com`

The above code does not work in this situation, which throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address
;
  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address

at com.ycs.tenjin.mail.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:86)
at com.ycs.tenjin.mail.EmailUtil.main(EmailUtil.java:19)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address
;
  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.ycs.tenjin.mail.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:80)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1616)
... 5 more
```

However, if I try set the from and to addresses to the conventional format, i.e. `s.sriram@mydomain.com`, then I get an Authentication unsuccessful error, like the one below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

at com.ycs.tenjin.mail.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:85)
at com.ycs.tenjin.mail.EmailUtil.main(EmailUtil.java:19)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at com.ycs.tenjin.mail.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:79)
... 1 more
```

Either way, this does not work.

Now, the customer tells me that he has another application where he has been able to successfully configure and send emails with the same MS Exchange server and the from & to address being specified like `MYDOMAIN\s.sriram`. I was even shown the other application's email configuration screen, where there was an option to explicitly choose **NTLM** as the authentication type. All other parameters were the same as what I have described in my code snippet above.

Is there a way we can set authentication type to NTLM instead of SMTP?

If no, could anyone suggest a way out of this problem?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the to/from addresses with the username for authentication. The first error you show indicates that authentication succeeded, but sending failed because you use something that isn't a valid address (`MYDOMAIN\s.sriram` is not a valid address). Similarly `mail.smtp.submitter` probably should also be a valid email address or maybe even left out entirely. In any case, you should post the output with `mail.debug` set to true.